# Extract cell value from table based on another cells value

Tags: php, html, arrays, dom

HTML file:
    http://www.arifoorum.com/test/html.htm

I got this html contents with simplehtmldom library:

```
array(66) {
  [0]=>
  array(14) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Item"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "Date, time:"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "mõõdikud"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "Name 2"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "Name 3"
    [5]=>
    string(9) "Meter ID:"
    [6]=>
    string(6) "V_HeEn"
    [7]=>
    string(6) "U_HeEn"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "V_V"
    [9]=>
    string(3) "U_V"
    [10]=>
    string(6) "V_InTe"
    [11]=>
    string(6) "U_InTe"
    [12]=>
    string(6) "V_OuTe"
    [13]=>
    string(6) "U_OuTe"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(14) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(19) "24.01.2013 22:23:33"
    [2]=>
    string(9) "Meter 002"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "&nbsp;"
    [4]=>
    string(6) "&nbsp;"
    [5]=>
    string(8) "40380040"
    [6]=>
    string(6) "&nbsp;"
    [7]=>
    string(6) "&nbsp;"
    [8]=>
    string(6) "&nbsp;"
    [9]=>
    string(6) "&nbsp;"
    [10]=>
    string(6) "&nbsp;"
    [11]=>
    string(6) "&nbsp;"
    [12]=>
    string(6) "&nbsp;"
    [13]=>
    string(6) "&nbsp;"
  }
  [2]=>
  ...
  }
}
```

Full output: http://www.arifoorum.com/test/test.php

**How do I get certain element from that array?**

For example: lets say i want value where `mõõdikud = 01` and `name 2 = külm` (that should be 72,114) .

Thanks

Comment: I am sorry, im pretty newb with arrays. Words Iterate and compare doesnt help without example :(

Comment: The PHP manual has a [nice page about arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). I really recommend to read it if you are not very familiar with arrays yet. Loops are language constructs that lets you repeat a set of commands as long a condition is fulfilled and you can use them to iterate over each element of the array. Have a look at the [`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) and [`foreach` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 1):

This could be useful for other users, so I made a little function that gets the value of a cell from a table, based on values of other cells (conditions):

```
function getCellValue(DOMElement $table, $cellName = null, array $conditions = array()){

  // get all table rows
  $trs = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr');  

  // assume first TR is the table header
  $head = $trs->item(0);

  // find cell names and their index
  $keys = array();
  foreach($head->childNodes as $th)
    if(!($th instanceof DomText))
      $keys[] = trim($th->nodeValue);

  if($invalidKeys = array_diff(array_keys($conditions), $keys))
    throw new Exception(sprintf('Non-extistent key(s) in table: ', implode(', ', $invalidKeys)));

  // find the row that meets all conditions
  $targetRow = null;
  foreach($table->childNodes as $tr){

    // internal counter because we can't rely on DOM index
    $idx = 0;
    foreach($tr->childNodes as $td){

      if($td instanceof DomText)
        continue;

      $value = trim($td->nodeValue);

      // check if all conditions match
      if(array_key_exists($keys[$idx], $conditions))
        $targetRow = ($value != $conditions[$keys[$idx]]) ? null : $tr;

      $idx++;    
    }

    // stop if we found a match
    if($targetRow)
      break;
  }

  if(!$targetRow)
    throw new Exception('No row matches your conditions');

  // build an array with row cells
  $values = array();
  $idx = 0;
  foreach($targetRow->childNodes as $td)
    if(!($td instanceof DomText))
      $values[$keys[$idx++]] = trim($td->nodeValue);

  // return the cell value if a specific cell was requested
  if($cellName !== null)
    return isset($values[$cellName]) ? $values[$cellName] : null;

  // otherwise return all values from the matched row
  return $values;
}
```

It uses [`DomDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) because the question wasn't tagged as [simplehtmldom](/questions/tagged/simplehtmldom)

@OP: in your case you would use it like:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.arifoorum.com/test/html.htm');

$dom = new DomDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->loadHtml($html);

$table = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(0);

print getCellValue($table, 'V_V', array(
  'mõõdikud' => '01',
  'Name 2'   => 'külm',
));
```