# Reading Another Website in PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I have a PHP script that creates a calendar and highlights the current day and everything. I want to open a website and read a table like the one below, and getting the "info" for a "date" and put it on my calendar.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Info</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2/20/2013</td>
<td>Meeting</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2/24/2013</td>
<td>Another meeting</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

With this code:

```
$url = $pageurl;
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$needle = $month . '/' . $list_day . '/' . $year;
if (strpos($content, $needle)) {
    $calendar .= '<p>STUFF</p><p>MORE STUFF</p>';
}
```

I have been somwhat successful, I can now output "STUFF" and "MORE STUFF" onto a day that appears on the calendar. But now I want to post exactly what that stuff is for that day. How can I do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14548282/1058140). You can copy the `getCellValue()` function from there, and use it like:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$dom->loadHtml('...table HTML here...');

$table = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(0);

print getCellValue($table, 'Info', array(
  'Date' => '2/20/2013',
));
```

This should print the corresponding "Info" value for the requested date ("Meeting")

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use something like a DOM parser. I've looked for "DOM Parser PHP" in Google and this was the first link:

[Library for DOM Parsing in PHP](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)